# Error al insertar multiples checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trarando de ingresar los presupuestos dentro de una base de datos pero tengo un error cuando eleigo entre una opcion y otra.

Intente hacerlo con un `array` pero guardaba todo dentro de una misma fila y no eso lo que estoy buscando y no se me ocurre como solucionarlo. Dejo el codigo completo para que me orienten y agradezco de antemano.

**ACTUALIZADO 2**

> Error 1: Los datos no pueden ingresar a la base de datos si no eligo todas las opciones.
>
> Error 2: Al usar `array` ingresa solo los datos nombre, email y total. Las otras casillas ingresa la palabra `array`.
>
> NOTA: Los iten no seleccionados deberian guardarse con valor `0`, algo que no se logra

**ACTUALIZADO 3**

Modificando el script de PHP, logro insertear el total, nombre, el mail pero despues me guarda la palabra `Array` en las otras casillas.

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){

    $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO presupuesto (nombre, email, total, bsimple, todo, frenos, aros) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :total, :bsimple, :todo, :frenos, :aros)");
    $add->bindValue(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $add->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $add->bindValue(':total', $_POST['total']);
    $add->bindValue(':bsimple', $_POST['check_list']);
    $add->bindValue(':todo', $_POST['check_list']);
    $add->bindValue(':frenos', $_POST['check_list']);
    $add->bindValue(':aros', $_POST['check_list']);
    $add->execute();

    echo '<div class="mb-3 badge badge-success">Presupuesto creado</div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="mb-3 badge badge-danger">Error</div>';
}
}
```

```js
function actualizarValor(estaChequeado, valor) {

var suma_actual = 0;
var campo_resultado = document.getElementById('txtValor');
valor = parseInt(valor);

try {
  if (campo_resultado != null) {
    if (isNaN(campo_resultado.value)) {
    campo_resultado.value = 0;
    }
    suma_actual = parseInt(campo_resultado.value);
  }
} catch (ex) {
  alert('No existe el campo de la suma.');
}

if (estaChequeado == true) {
  suma_actual = suma_actual + valor;
  $(this).closest("label").css('border', '3px solid black');
} else {
  suma_actual = suma_actual - valor;
  $(this).closest("label").css('border', '3px solid transparent');
}

campo_resultado.value = suma_actual;
}
```

```css
.checkeable img {
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
.checkeable input {
  display: none;
}
.checkeable input:checked  + img {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Presupuesto</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<h2>Mi Bicicleta</h2>
<div style="padding-top: 1rem;">
<p>Presupuesto</p>
<span style="font-size: 1.4rem;">U$S</span>
<input type="text" name="total" style="font-size: 1.4rem; padding: .4rem; border: none;" readonly id="txtValor" value="0">
</div>

<div class="pt-4">

<label class="checkeable">
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/bicycle-512.png"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="simple" value="60" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);"> Bicicleta Simple $60
</label>

<label class="checkeable ml-3">
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/bicycle-512.png"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="todo" value="86" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);"> Todo Terreno $86
</label>

</div>

<div class="pt-4">
<h4>Como quieres armar tu bicicleta?</h4>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="frenoapb" value="180" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);"> Frenos APB - $180
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="aros" value="82" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);"> Aros de aluminio - $82
</p>

<p>
<input type="text" name="nombre" > Nombre
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="email"> Email
</p>

<button name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Presupuesto</button>
</form>


</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: Es que no me deja ingresar los datos sin haber elegido todos los checkbox. Si eligo una opcion, no me deja ingresarlos datos, es como que tengo que elegir todo y no es lo correcto, tiene que ser o una bicibleta simple o todo terreno

Comment: hola, cuál es el comportamiento deseado en base a todo lo que ya tienes hecho? no entiendo muy bien

Comment: Uno de los problemas principales en tu código es que usas funciones *in line*, lo cual es una mala práctica. Me refiero a que pones en el `onclick` de cada checkbox una función `actualizarValor()` Luego, la lógica en esa función es confusa. ¿Por qué no recoges todos los elementos del formulario simplemente con algo como serialize (en ese caso los checkbox que no estén seleccionados no se recogerán) y envías esos datos? Y, si debe elegirse una sola opción entre varias, lo propio sería un radio, no un checkbox.

Comment: El problema es que los checkbox no se agregan a POST si no estan seleccionados.  Necesitas chequear si el valor esta presente en POST con `isset()` y si no poner un valor por default.

Comment: @A.Cedano - Con `PHP` me puedo manejar bien, ya utilizar `serialize` no se como hacerlo, el script en `JavaScript`, no lo hice yo, algo entiendo, pero tengo que cambiar todo. Respecto al porque checkbox y no al radio es porque dentro de la categoria `asientos`, el comprador puede elegir si lo quiere de cuero o estampado o conbinarlos ambos. Si utilizo radio es uno u otro y la idea del cliente es combinar todo.

Comment: Decía lo de los radio en caso de que se necesite solamente uno entre varios, si no es así está claro que debes quedarte con los checkbox. Dado que estás usando jQuery, puedes simplificar tu lógica haciendo esto: `$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {  event.preventDefault(); var mData=$( this ).serialize(); });` Ahí tendrás en `mData` todos los elementos del formulario que tengan algún valor, luego, en el servidor, puedes verificar qué checkbox  fueron llenados y en base a eso asignar los valores en la BD. Como te dije antes, usar funciones *in line* sólo arroja confusión al código.

Comment: Toda la lógica que tenga que ver con el envío del formulario iría dentro de ese bloque donde creas `mData`  y de paso puedes implementar Ajax para transmitir los datos al servidor, pudiendo recibir la respuesta sin necesidad de refrescar la página. Aunque tengas poco dominio de Javascript, son cosas mínimas que deberías aprender y que te van a ahorrar muchísimo trabajo. Estamos ante un problema sencillo, pero abordado desde una solución complicada expresada en tu función `actualizarValor()`. Yo te recomiendo que simplifiques y que uses las herramientas adecuadas.

Comment: Ok, voy a ir actualizando el codigo e ir subiendo. Voy a estudiar un poco y vengo!

Comment: @A.Cedano, entiendo lo que decis de utilizar las herramientas adecuadas, pero conozco poco `jquery` y he tratado de resolver las cosas desde PHP. En este caso, aprendo algo nuevo, pero no como sinplificar el codigo si es respecto a `JQuery` y `JavaScript`. Busque lo que tu me has dicho, no supo aplicar tu ejemplo, pero use uno de la pagina de Jquery. Toma los datos dentro del etiqueta `p`, y eso tendria que usar `AJAX`?

Comment: Veo que intentas leer el contenido de la variable $_POST['check_list'] pero no está definida en el HTML, te sugiero que hagas un echo print_r($_POST, true) para que veas cuáles son realmente las variables POST que debes usar.

Comment: @track3r este es lo que sale cuando ingresa los datos: `Array ( [total] => 142 [check_list] => Array ( [0] => 60 [1] => 82 ) [nombre] => df [email] => sebastian.dcnx@gmail.com [add] => Crear `

Comment: Entonces check_list es un array, debes acceder por lo tanto como tal, más o menos así: $v = $POST["check_list"][0];

Comment: Ahi lo probe y me agregar a la base de datos el total, el nombre, el correo y si tomo un valor, me lo llena en todas las casillas restantes

Comment: Bueno, en cada campo tienes que cambiar el elemento del array, por ejemplo, el primero [0], pero el segundo [1], de todas formas, no está muy bien planteado tal como lo tienes

Comment: entiendo e hice varios cambios, pero no logro resolverlo... trate de hacer lo que me recomendo Cedano, pero hice todo mal... volvi a donde estaba y voy a tratar de resolverlo con PHP... gracias Track3r

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Los input checkbox se envían solo si la casilla está marcada, por lo que debes verificar que realmente se recibieron en PHP. Lo más fácil es con asignación ternaria:

`(sentencia booleana) ? valor si la sentencia es cierta : valor si es falsa`

```
// Con un if usarías:
if(isset($_POST['algo']) {
    $variable = $_POST['algo'];
} else {
    $variable = 0;
}

// Con asignación ternaria:
$variable = ($_POST['algo']) ? $_POST['algo'] : 0;
```

Funciona igual con echo, asignar parámetros, incluir como valor de array, etc.

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
        $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO presupuesto (nombre, email, total, bsimple, todo, frenos, aros) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :total, :bsimple, :todo, :frenos, :aros)");
        $add->bindValue(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
        $add->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $add->bindValue(':total', $_POST['total']);
        // Con asignación ternaria revisas que el checkbox fue marcado
        $add->bindValue(':bsimple', (isset($_POST['bsimple']) ? $_POST['bsimple'] : 0);
        $add->bindValue(':todo', (isset($_POST['todo']) ? $_POST['todo'] : 0);
        $add->bindValue(':frenos', (isset($_POST['frenos']) ? $_POST['frenos'] : 0);
        $add->bindValue(':aros', (isset($_POST['aros']) ? $_POST['aros'] : 0);
        $add->execute();
        echo '<div class="mb-3 badge badge-success">Presupuesto creado</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="mb-3 badge badge-danger">Error</div>';
    }
}
```

En el HTML coloca los nombres igual que los campos de tu tabla:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Presupuesto</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<h2>Mi Bicicleta</h2>
<div style="padding-top: 1rem;">
<p>Presupuesto</p>
<span style="font-size: 1.4rem;">U$S</span>
<input type="text" name="total" style="font-size: 1.4rem; padding: .4rem; border: none;" readonly id="txtValor" value="0">
</div>

<div class="pt-4">

<label class="checkeable">
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/bicycle-512.png"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bsimple" value="60" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);"> Bicicleta Simple $60
</label>

<label class="checkeable ml-3">
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/bicycle-512.png"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="todo" value="86" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);"> Todo Terreno $86
</label>

</div>

<div class="pt-4">
<h4>Como quieres armar tu bicicleta?</h4>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="frenos" value="180" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);"> Frenos APB - $180
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="aros" value="82" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);"> Aros de aluminio - $82
</p>

<p>
<input type="text" name="nombre" > Nombre
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="email"> Email
</p>

<button name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Presupuesto</button>
</form>


</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Te mostraré una solución aplicando lo que te sugerí en varios comentarios.

## HTML

Evitaremos las funciones *in line*, porque son una mala práctica debido a que arrastran en el HTML código Javascript. Si mañana hay que cambiar algo en esa función tendrás que buscar todos los HTML que la tengan y modificarlos.

Aquí lo que haremos será *escuchar* el envío del formulario, recogeremos sus datos con `serialize` y en el servidor verificaremos qué datos se mandaron y qué datos no.

Otra cosa que deberías evitar es el uso de `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, pues en algunos contextos puede ser un problema de seguridad. No nos detendremos en eso ahora, pero si quieres luego te paso un enlace a una pregunta que ahora no recuerdo. En su lugar vamos a poner el nombre del archivo que procesará la información que pases al servidor, y que debe ser otro distinto del archivo que contiene el formulario. Aquí he llamado a ese archivo `form-action.php` y he supuesto que se encuentra en el mismo directorio que el script que contiene el formulario.

Hemos agregado también un `<div id="result">` para mostrar el resultado de la petición Ajax. Esto es opcional y depende de tu contexto.

Bueno, este es el HTML.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Presupuesto</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form action="form-action.php" method="post">
<h2>Mi Bicicleta</h2>
<div style="padding-top: 1rem;">
<p>Presupuesto</p>
<span style="font-size: 1.4rem;">U$S</span>
<input type="text" name="total" style="font-size: 1.4rem; padding: .4rem; border: none;" readonly id="txtValor" value="0">
</div>

<div class="pt-4">

<label class="checkeable">
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/bicycle-512.png"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="simple" value="60" /> Bicicleta Simple $60
</label>

<label class="checkeable ml-3">
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/bicycle-512.png"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="todo" value="86" /> Todo Terreno $86
</label>

</div>

<div class="pt-4">
<h4>Como quieres armar tu bicicleta?</h4>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="frenoapb" value="180" /> Frenos APB - $180
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="aros" value="82" /> Aros de aluminio - $82
</p>

<p>
<input type="text" name="nombre" /> Nombre
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="email" /> Email
</p>

<button name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Presupuesto</button>
</form>


</div>

<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Javacript

Este sería el código JS que estaría en el mismo archivo que el HTML y que recogería los datos y los enviaría al servidos vía Ajax. Este bloque completo lo puedes poner dentro de la etiqueta `head` del HTML anterior.

```
$(function() {
    $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        /* 
            *Dado que $( this ) hace referencia al formulario
            *Lo usaremos para serialize, y también para determinar
            *a qué URL debe dirigirse la petición
            *y cuál es su método, mediante prop
        */
        var mData=$( this ).serialize(); 
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: $( this ).prop('action'),
            method: $( this ).prop('method'),
            data: mData,
            dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            $('#result').html(msg);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert(`La petición falló ${textStatus}`);
        });

    }); 

});
```

## PHP

Ahora en PHP vamos a usar ternarios para determinar qué valores llegaron en la petición. Dado que los checkbox que no se seleccionaron no van a viajar entre los datos que se manden, mediante un ternario podremos asignar el valor por defecto que es `0`, según dices en la pregunta, cuando esos datos no hayan sido seleccionados.

**NOTA**: Este archivo debe llamarse **`form-action.php`** o el nombre que sea, pero deber ser igual que lo que hayas escrito en la etiqueta `action` del formulario.

```
$nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
$email= !empty($_POST['email'])  ? $_POST['email']  : NULL;
if ($nombre && $email) {
    #Aquí los ternarios asignarán 0 cuando alguno de los checkbox no se haya marcado
    $total=!empty($_POST['total']) ? $_POST['total'] : 0;
    $bsimple=!empty($_POST['simple']) ? $_POST['simple'] : 0;
    $todo=!empty($_POST['todo']) ? $_POST['todo'] : 0;
    $frenos=!empty($_POST['frenoapb']) ? $_POST['frenoapb'] : 0;
    $aros=!empty($_POST['aros']) ? $_POST['aros'] : 0;
    $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO presupuesto (nombre, email, total, bsimple, todo, frenos, aros) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :total, :bsimple, :todo, :frenos, :aros)");
    $add->bindValue(':nombre', $nombre);
    $add->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $add->bindValue(':total', $total);
    $add->bindValue(':bsimple', $bsimple);
    $add->bindValue(':todo', $todo);
    $add->bindValue(':frenos', $frenos);
    $add->bindValue(':aros', $aros);
    #Hay que controlar un posible fallo del execute
    #para no poner tantos echo usaremos variables de estado
    if ( $add->execute() ) {
        $type="success";
        $msg="Presupuesto creado";
    } else {
        $type="danger";
        $msg="Error ejecutando la consulta. Posible clave duplicada.";
    }
} else {
        $type="danger";
        $msg="Error. Hay datos vacíos en el post.";
}
echo "<div class=\"mb-3 badge badge-$type\">$msg</div>";
```

Eso es todo. Prueba esto y si tienes algún problema hazlo saber en comentarios.

Answer (score 4):

Una solución para tu problema es validar con `isset()` si el valor existe, si no, agregar uno por defecto, luego agregar a cada `input` un nombre distinto y crear inputs ocultos para guardar los valores reales a procesar.

Puedes pegar esta función en tu código php, úsala para obtener tus valores.

```php
 // valida que el input exista si no existe o esta vació retorna el valor $por_defecto
 function getPOST($el_input, $por_defecto= 0) {
     return isset($_POST[$el_input]) ? ( $_POST[el_input] != "" ? $_POST[el_input]  : $por_defecto)  : $por_defecto;
}

 $total = getPOST("total");
 $bsimple = getPOST("bsimple");
 $todo = getPOST("todo");
 $frenos = getPOST("frenos",0.00); // si no existe $frenos igual a 0.00
 $aros = getPOST("aros", 0 ); // si no existe $aros igual a 0
 $nombre= getPOST("nombre","sin nombre");
```

**1.** Ya que tu tabla requiere `nombre, email, total, bsimple, todo, frenos, aros` creo esos `input` con el atributo `type=text`.

**2.** Luego para saber el tipo de bicicleta creo un par de inputs con `name=tipo` y de `type=radio` esto permite enviar el `tipo` y a los input de nombre  `bsimple` y `todo` agrego `hidden` para ocultarlos y así estos siempre serán enviados por formulario.

**3.** Cambia los valores según la selección usado el `id` para saber que input cambiar y el evento `onclick` ( cuando se da click en la opción visible para `bsimple` cambia `bsimple` a 65 y `todo` a 0 y viceversa )

```html
<li>Total:<input name="total" disabled requiered></li>
<li><label>
  <input id="bsimple" name="bsimple" hidden>
  <input name="tipo" type="radio"     onclick="bsimple.value=65;todo.value=0;"> Simple
<label>
<label>
  <input id="todo" name="todo" hidden>
  <input name="tipo" type="radio"     onclick="bsimple.value=0;todo.value=65;"> Todo
<label>
</li>
<li>Frenos:<input name="frenos" value="50" type="checkbox"></li>
<li>Aros:<input name="aros"  value="60" type="checkbox"></li>
<li>Nombre:<input name="nombre" requiered></li>
<li>Email: <input name="email" requiered></li>
```

Por ultimo en tu código PHP recuerda pegar la función de arriba.

## CHECKBOX Y RADIO :

Primero debes recordar que los `inputs` de tipo checkbox solo se envían por `POST` o `GET` cuando han sido seleccionados, para saber si algo llega por formulario debes usar la funcion `isset($_POST["tudato"])` una buena manera de verificar que llego a tu petición es asiendo un `echo` del `$_POST`.

```php
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Si tiene esto en tu formulario.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="banana">
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="2">
```

como te das cuenta ninguno de estos esta seleccionado, no tiene `checked` entonces la estructura de `$_POST` seria `[]` un array vació por lo tanto  `isset($_POST["foo"])` y `isset($_POST["bar"])` seria `false` para ambos casos, pero si es este otro caso.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="banana" checked>
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="2" checked>
```

la estructura de `$_POST` seria `[ foo=banana , bar=1 ]`, ya son accesibles y `asset[$_POST["foo"]]` y `asset[$_POST["foo"]]` daría true.

si estas usando los `checkobox` para la lógica de tu formulario, debes complementar con otro elemento de html que son los input de tipo `radio`.

- `type="checkbox"` es un input usado para enviar un valor solo si este es seleccionado.
- `type="radio"` es un input usado para enviar solo un valor de varias opciones a seleccionar.