# Obtener valor del checbox cuando no esta marcado en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, formularios, checkbox

Hola estoy creando dos checkbox de notificaciones así que el cliente decida si quiere recibir notificaciones por whatsaap y por sms

[image: Asi son las opciones]

Este es el código

```html
 <form method="post" action="http://localhost/gomobile/track-2/" >
  <input class="form-check-input" name="whatsaap" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" value="si">  
 <br>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sms" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" value="si">
 <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Asi obtengo los valores

```
if (isset($_POST['whatsaap'])  ){   
    $value = $_POST['whatsaap'] ;
    update_post_meta (24332, 'notifications-what', $value) ;    
}
```

pero cuando se envia el valor solo lo guarda si esta marcado que el valor es 'si', pero me gustaria que guardara un valor cuando este vacio como false o no, pero solo obtengo el valor marcado. Gracias

Comment: Podrias hacer una validacion que agarre solamente si recibe un valor y si no, entonces puedes asignarle un false por defecto

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/322989/54039), seguramente te será útil.

Comment: Ya lo hice  antes con ``else    {    update_post_meta (24332, 'notifications-what', false ); } `` pero entoces si el usuario marca la de sms y no la de whatsaap el valor de whatsaap pasa a false